# Cubic Approximation to $e^x$ using Chebyshev Polynomial

Tags: definite-integrals, chebyshev-polynomials, chebyshev-function

Was trying to solve this: $C_r=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1\frac{e^xT_r(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

where $r=0,1,2,3$

$T_r(x) =cosr[{cos}^{-1}x]$

While solving, I equated $x=cos\theta$

Therefore $T_r(x)=cosr\theta$

and $dx=-\sqrt{1-x^2}d\theta$
$$C_r=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{\pi}^0\frac{e^{cos\theta}cosr\theta}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.-\sqrt{1-x^2}d\theta$$

Solving further
$$C_r=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}e^{cos\theta}cosr\theta d\theta$$

When $r=0$, $C_r=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}e^{cos\theta} d\theta$

When $r=1$, $C_r=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}e^{cos\theta}cos\theta d\theta$

And so on. The problem is to now calculate the definite integrals without resorting to approximations using Trapezoid or Simpsons rule.

Comment: Any substitution idea or something else for the definite integrals?

Comment: None. That's why I asked to know if anyone can be of assistance.

Comment: I have gone it a little far, but I need some more integrals... Are you sure it can be evaluated using antiderivatives? Or not at all?

Comment: I don't know if it can be evaluated or not. It's just that the functions looks very simple thus I feel it should.

Comment: Im trying to to solve the same problem atm, trying different approaches like integration by parts and eulers identity, but just find my self getting more complext integrals. I hope somebody answers this :)