# Antiderivative of $\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, integral-transforms

Can anyone help me find the following indefinite integral:

$$\int{\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx}$$

I cannot think of any transformation...

Comment: Do you have some reason to think there is an answer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is used in another's exercise solution in my textbook, so since there is a solution (only final arithmetic result is listed, not the whole solution) to that other exercise, we should be able to find the integral listed above...

Comment: Details, please. What's the other exercise? How does the solution to the other exercise use this one?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The same [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373356/cubic-approximation-to-ex-using-chebyshev-polynomial). This is the exercise... And it is also on my Greek textbook for advanced calculus.

Comment: I don't follow. All I see at that link is some definite integrals. Your question is about an indefinite integral. Please: What is the other exercise? How does the solution to the other exercise use this one?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The link I gave to you results to a definite integral of $e^{\cos \theta}$ which results (with substitution of $x= \cos \theta$) to the above integral in this question.

Comment: A definite integral cannot result in an indefinite integral. For the third time: what is the other exercise? How does the solution to the other exercise use this one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26384/discussion-between-jason-and-gerry-myerson).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat. So, for the fourth time, what is the other exercise? How does the solution to the other exercise use this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I cannot think of any transformation*

No wonder you can't, since even its definite counterpart requires the presence of special [Bessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) functions:

> $$\int_0^1\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}~dx~=~\frac\pi2\Big(I_0(1)+L_0(1)\Big),$$
>
> $$\int_{-1}^0\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}~dx~=~\frac\pi2\Big(I_0(1)-L_0(1)\Big).$$